# If $x^2 - 3x + 2$ is a factor of $x^4 - px^2 +q$, then find the value of $p$ and $q$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $x^2 - 3x +2$ is a factor of $x^4-px^2+q$ then find the value of $p$ and $q$.

My attempt:

$$x^2-3x+2$$
$$x^2-2x-x+2$$
$$x(x-2)-1(x-2)$$
$$(x-1)(x-2)$$

How do I proceed further?

P.S: Edit after Deepak's comment!

Comment: $1,2$ are roots of $g(x) := x^4 - px^2 + 9$.

Comment: @A---B, I didn't get answer this way.

Comment: Why ? what is the problem ?

Comment: @A---B, the answer is $5,4$

Comment: It can't possible be. since for $p= 4$, $g(x) = x^4 - 4x^2 + 9$ and $g(1) = 1 - 4 + 9 = 6$ but your $f(x) := x^2 -3x + 2$ is $0$ for $x = 1$. Since we have $f(x) h(x) = g(x)$ where $h(x)$ is some polynomial, for $x = 1$ we get $6 = 0$. contradiction.

Comment: Usually, problems like this have an added "degree of freedom", i.e. another variable to solve for (such as the constant term being '$q$') so you can get a non-contradictory solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT1

Factors of $ (x^2 - 3 x + 2) $ are $(x-1),(x-2)$  and each factor produces a zero remainder. Each factor zero remainder requires that

$$ 1-p+q = 0, \, 16-4p+q = 0  $$

Solving

$$ p=5, q=4 $$

and original expression was

$$ x^4 - 5 x^2 + 4 =(x-1)(x+1)(x-2)(x+2)$$

BTW the answer is same even if problem is set in any of six ways..

$$(x^2-3x+2),(x^2-x-2),..,..,..$$

is a factor of $ x^4-px^2+ q $  etc.

Comment: @Narsimham, what's the difference in yours and quasi's answers?

Comment: Essentially the same..I wanted to state that *each* factor has the same zero  remainder.

Answer (score 4):

Since $1$ and $2$ are zeros of $x^2 - 3x + 2$, they must also be zeros of $x^4-px^2+q.$

Substituting $x=1\,$ into $x^4-px^2+q\,$ yields $1-p+q = 0$.

Substituting $x=2\,$ into $x^4-px^2+q\,$ yields $16-4p+q = 0$.

So now you have two equations in two unknowns.

Comment: I have edited the question. Please check the edited version.

Answer (score 1):

Using long division:

$$ \frac{x^4 - px^2 + q}{x^2-3x+2} = x^2 + 3x + \frac{(7-p)x^2 - 6x +q}{x^2-3x+2}.$$

Look at the last fraction. By inspection, the ratio will be equal to $2$ if

$$ 7-p = 2 \implies p = 5$$
$$q = 4$$

Note: Previously, I mistook $q$ for $9$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use polynomial division to and divide the two polynomials, then, since $x^2-3x+2$ is a factor, the remainder has to be $0$